# How to add margins to text of pdf pages generated by Puppeteer while keeping the background color intact

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, puppeteer

I am generating pdfs using puppeteer with dynamic content.

I want to add margins/padding below and above the text in consecutive pages.

When I use the property margin: { top: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }, this adds margins, but the background color of the page also gets the margin since that is the content receiving the margin property.

Is there a way to only apply margins/padding to the text. Since this is dynamic data, we cant add the padding property on the content.

Screenshots of the pdf generated without margin and with margin respectively

[image: without margin property]

[image: image with margin property]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass styling in headerTemplate and footerTemplate.